# Android Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, build, gradle

I need to load html file in webview, but this html contains a lot of scripts and other resourses. So i put my index.html and two folders with resourses to my assets folder. Now when i'm trying to build my project i got this error:

```
:app:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to add E:\Projects\PressurIce\app\build\intermediates\resources\resources-debug.ap_

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The first question is: anybody know what does it mean ?
The second question is: how can i do this thing:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

to see more logs ? Thx.

**UPDATE 1**

Run with --stacktrace give more info:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

Caused by: com.android.builder.packaging.PackagerException: Failed to add E:\Projects\PressurIce\app\build\intermediates\resources\resources-debug.ap_
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager.addZipFile(Packager.java:422)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager.<init>(Packager.java:307)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.packageApk(AndroidBuilder.java:1474)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$packageApk$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.doFullTaskAction(PackageApplication.groovy:97)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
    at com.android.builder.signing.SignedJarBuilder.writeEntry(SignedJarBuilder.java:343)
    at com.android.builder.signing.SignedJarBuilder.writeZip(SignedJarBuilder.java:274)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.Packager.addZipFile(Packager.java:416)
    ... 67 more
```